# Regex matching {{> (lookup. 'superman')}}

Tags: php, regex

I need regex that will do result in following

Given this notation:

```
{{> (lookup. 'needle')}}
```

Tt returns result :

```
["needle"]
```

I tried with this one, but it matches everything `{{>\(.(.+?)}}`

Comment: Is the `lookup` part static? Then something like `{{> \(lookup\. (.+)\)}}` should do.

Comment: If you're only looking for the part in the single quotes, add them to your pattern: `{{>\(.*'([^']+)'\)}}`

Comment: If you need both the lookup and needle `{{>\s*\((.*)\.\s*\'(.*)\'\)}}` will give you both, especially if lookup is the method to use for the needle.

Comment: @NigelRen lookup part is static and I still need just `needle`.  Only thing that could change is number of spaces between `lookup` and `needle` but dot is still somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use make use of a capturing group and instead of a non greedy quantifier `.+?` make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

```
{{>\h*\([^(']+'([^')]+)'\)}}
```

- `{{>` Match {{>
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars (or `\h+` for 1 or more)
- `\([^(']+` Match `(` and then 1+ times any char except `(` or `'`
- `'(` Match `'` and start capture **group 1**

  - `[^')]+` Match 1+ times any char except `'` or `)`
- `)'` Close group 1 and match `'`
- `\)}}` Match `)}}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEX1cS/1)

In the replacement use

```
["$1"]
```

Output

```
["needle"]
```

**Edit**

If the `lookup` part should be static, you could update the pattern to:

```
{{>\h*\(lookup[^']+'([^')]+)'\)}}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5qopXD/1)

Comment: Thanks, could you modify it so it takes into consideration that `lookup` part is static ?

Comment: @unknown_coder Sure, do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/5qopXD/1 `{{>\h*\(lookup[^']+'([^')]+)'\)}}`

Answer (score 0):

If the notation is going to be exactly the same as written, `{{> \(lookup\s*\. '(.*?)'\)}}` should solve your problem. It looks for literal versions of all your characters, and then uses a capture group to collect only the text between `'` marks. (Note that this regex needs to be changed if the capture text includes `'` marks.)

Edit: regex now matches any number of spaces between `lookup` and `.`

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/68ZjlG/3/)

Comment: Lookup part is static, but spaces between lookup and `.` are not, this one won't match spaces if I'm correct?

Comment: @unknown_coder You are correct. See updated answer for a regex that matches spaces between `lookup` and `.`